# Using https for minio server

Tags: https, minio

I am trying to get a minio server to run on https but everytime i try to run it i get the following error:

```
{"level":"FATAL","time":"2018-06-15T15:12:19.2189519Z","error":{"message":"The 
parameter is incorrect.","source":["cmd\\server-main.go:225:cmd.serverMain()"]}}
```

I have followed the following guide:
https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls

And tried to generate my own certificate but nothing seems to work... I placed the certificates inside the .minio/certs folder and named them public.crt and private.key. I have tried to re-generate the certs over and over again but I am still getting that error message... If anyone can point me in the right direction, i would greatly appropriate it

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1:** you can generate the SSL Certificate if you don't have one, for example:

```
sudo mkdir -p /tmp/.minio/certs
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /tmp/.minio/certs/private.key -out /tmp/.minio/certs/public.crt
```

**Step 2:** run Minio sever secured by HTTPS. Here I'm using Docker with docker-compose:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    command: server --address ":443" /data
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: "YourAccesskey"
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: "YourSecretkey"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/minio/data:/data
      - /tmp/.minio:/root/.minio
```

Note: here assume that you have a directory on your host, called /tmp/minio/data. If you don't, create it: `mkdir -p /tmp/minio/data`

Now start the container: `docker-compose up`

That's it.

**Check:** You can access your Minio server via HTTPS, see below:

[image]

**References**

- https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls
- https://docs.minio.io/docs/generate-let-s-encypt-certificate-using-concert-for-minio.html

Comment: Is there a way to use other that 443 port and still enable https?

Answer (score 1):

if you using `sudo` you must have `private.key` and `public.crt` in `/root/.minio/certs/`. In my case, I must rename my `minio.key` and `minio.crt` because minio doesn't want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using minio-go client, then you can set `SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/ca.crt`